# Gesture Recognizer not working in UIScrollView Subclass

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, uiscrollview

I have subclassed `UIScrollView`, and i have a `UIScrollView` in my nib, Gestures were working fine on it, but when i changed the class of `UIScrollView` in Identity Inspector to my subclass of `UIScrollView`, the gestures stopped working, and i have this warning in my Interface Builder.

```
ScrollView does not have an outlet collection named gestureRecognizors.
```

Also i have a delegate in my subclass, which is also giving a warning:

Here is the Subclass:

```
@protocol ScrollViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)onScrollViewTouch;

@end


@interface ScrollView : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, retain) id<ScrollViewDelegate> subDelegate;

@end
```

Here is ScrollView.m

```
@implementation ScrollView

@synthesize subDelegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    self.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
    self.delaysContentTouches = NO;
    [self setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [super setDelegate: self];
}
return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
[delegate onScrollViewTouch];
}

@end
```

Can anyone suggest what am i doing wrong here? Thanks everyone :)

Comment: try changing ur subclass name, there might be like a keyword of that name..

Comment: i tried d same thing, works better, `touchesBegan` is called.. how u r setting `subDelegate` and r u adding any other `UIGestureRecognizer` on ur custom scrollview.?

Comment: Yes, UIGestureRecognizer are added through interface builder. Which are giving the mentioned warning and are not working. TouchBegins works fine.